# Android : app loading library at runtime on Lollipop but not IceCreamSandwich

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-5.0-lollipop, classnotfoundexception, android-4.3-jelly-bean

I'm currently developping an Android app using Android Studio. Currently, the app is launching perfectly on Lollipop devices, but crashes at launch due to a `ClassNotFoundException` on pre-lollipop devices (i've tested on ICS and it fail).

The missing class is always from an external librairies at runtime.

Here's the gradle file :

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23.0.0'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 'com.kappsports.kapp10'
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName '1.0.0'
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            shrinkResources true
        }
    }
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
    dexOptions {
        incremental true
        javaMaxHeapSize '4g'
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    jcenter()
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', exclude: 'android-support-v4.jar', include: '*.jar')
    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.1@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    compile 'com.michaelpardo:activeandroid:3.1.0-SNAPSHOT'
    compile 'com.github.johnpersano:supertoasts:1.3.4@aar'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3'
    compile 'com.squareup:otto:1.3.5'
    compile 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:1.3.0'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:6.0.0'
    compile 'com.malinskiy:superrecyclerview:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.jpardogo.materialtabstrip:library:1.0.9'
    compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.3'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.4.0'
    compile 'org.buraktamturk:loadingview:1.0.0@aar'
    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.1.0'
    compile 'com.github.navasmdc:MaterialDesign:1.5@aar'
    compile 'net.danlew:android.joda:2.8.2'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:22.2.1'

}
```

Here is a shunk of logcat output :

```
> 09-06 23:25:58.414  27436-27436/? W/dalvikvm﹕ Link of class
> 'Lio/fabric/sdk/android/InitializationTask;' failed 09-06 23:25:58.414
> 27436-27436/? E/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find class
> 'io.fabric.sdk.android.InitializationTask', referenced from method
> io.fabric.sdk.android.Kit.<init> 09-06 23:25:58.414  27436-27436/?
> W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve new-instance 8228
> (Lio/fabric/sdk/android/InitializationTask;) in
> Lio/fabric/sdk/android/Kit; 09-06 23:25:58.414  27436-27436/?
> D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x22 at 0x0003 09-06 23:25:58.414 
> 27436-27436/? W/dalvikvm﹕ Unable to resolve superclass of
> Lio/fabric/sdk/android/InitializationTask; (8269) 09-06 23:25:58.414 
> 27436-27436/? W/dalvikvm﹕ Link of class
> 'Lio/fabric/sdk/android/InitializationTask;' failed 09-06 23:25:58.414
> 27436-27436/? W/dalvikvm﹕ Unable to resolve superclass of
> Lio/fabric/sdk/android/InitializationTask; (8269) 09-06 23:25:58.414 
> 27436-27436/? W/dalvikvm﹕ Link of class
> 'Lio/fabric/sdk/android/InitializationTask;' failed 09-06 23:25:58.414
> 27436-27436/? I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method
> io.fabric.sdk.android.InitializationTask.getDependencies, referenced
> from method io.fabric.sdk.android.Kit.getDependencies 09-06
> 23:25:58.414  27436-27436/? W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual
> method 57413:
> Lio/fabric/sdk/android/InitializationTask;.getDependencies
> ()Ljava/util/Collection; 09-06 23:25:58.414  27436-27436/? D/dalvikvm﹕
> VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002 09-06 23:25:58.414  27436-27436/?
> W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature
> (Lio/fabric/sdk/android/services/common/IdManager;) 09-06 23:25:58.414
> 27436-27436/? W/dalvikvm﹕ Unable to resolve superclass of
> Lio/fabric/sdk/android/InitializationTask; (8269) 09-06 23:25:58.414 
> 27436-27436/? W/dalvikvm﹕ Link of class
> 'Lio/fabric/sdk/android/InitializationTask;' failed 09-06 23:25:58.414
> 27436-27436/? W/dalvikvm﹕ Unable to resolve superclass of
> Lio/fabric/sdk/android/InitializationTask; (8269) 09-06 23:25:58.414 
> 27436-27436/? W/dalvikvm﹕ Link of class
> 'Lio/fabric/sdk/android/InitializationTask;' failed 09-06 23:25:58.414
> 27436-27436/? I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method
> io.fabric.sdk.android.InitializationTask.executeOnExecutor, referenced
> from method io.fabric.sdk.android.Kit.initialize 09-06 23:25:58.414 
> 27436-27436/? W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 57412:
> Lio/fabric/sdk/android/InitializationTask;.executeOnExecutor
> (Ljava/util/concurrent/ExecutorService;[Ljava/lang/Object;)V 09-06
> 23:25:58.414  27436-27436/? D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at
> 0x0011 09-06 23:25:58.414  27436-27436/? W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to
> find class referenced in signature
> (Lio/fabric/sdk/android/services/common/IdManager;) 09-06 23:25:58.419
> 27436-27436/? W/dalvikvm﹕ Unable to resolve superclass of
> Lio/fabric/sdk/android/InitializationTask; (8269) 09-06 23:25:58.419 
> 27436-27436/? W/dalvikvm﹕ Link of class
> 'Lio/fabric/sdk/android/InitializationTask;' failed 09-06 23:25:58.419
> 27436-27436/? D/dalvikvm﹕ DexOpt: unable to opt direct call 0xe03e at
> 0x05 in Lio/fabric/sdk/android/Kit;.<init> 09-06 23:25:58.419 
> 27436-27436/? D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM 09-06 23:25:58.419 
> 27436-27436/? W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught
> exception (group=0x41bfb700) 09-06 23:25:58.419  27436-27436/?
> E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>     java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io.fabric.sdk.android.services.common.ExecutorUtils
>             at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsCore.<init>(CrashlyticsCore.java:205)
>             at com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsCore$Builder.build(CrashlyticsCore.java:189)
>             at com.kappsports.kapp10.Kapp10Application.onCreate(Kapp10Application.java:53)
>             at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1024)
>             at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4684)
>             at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1400(ActivityThread.java:159)
>             at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1376)
>             at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>             at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
>             at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
>             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
>             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
>             at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
>             at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 09-06 23:25:58.424    2346-2891/? I/ActivityManager﹕ Notify an
> ApplicationCrash
```

I'm currently out of solution for now. Any clue about that would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Regards.

Comment: Add the output of the exception to your question.

Comment: The crash is almost certainly due to using multidex in your application. Whatever class is not being found is most likely being accessed before attachBaseContext has been called in your application and the secondary dexes are loaded. Did you follow the multidex example and make sure it is being initialised in your Application class?

Comment: Post the logcat with the  classnotdeffoundexception

Comment: i've just added a shunk of logcat output, thanks for helping :)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

**1)** Add multidex support to your app:

```
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
```

**2)** Set your application as a `MultiDexApplication`. Select one of the options below:

This is the source code of android's `MultiDexApplication` class:

```
public class MultiDexApplication extends Application {
    public MultiDexApplication() {
    }

    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
        MultiDex.install(this);
    }
}
```

**Option 1)** You can extend your custom application from `MultiDexApplication`:

```
public class MyApplication extends MultiDexApplication {
    // Your application implementation here
}
```

**Option 2)** You can extend your custom application from default `Application` class, then you need to call `MultiDex.install` at `attachBaseContext(Context base)` method:

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
        MultiDex.install(this);
    }

    // Your application implementation here
}
```

**Option 3)** If you don't have any custom application and you don't want any, simply set your application name (at AndroidManifest.xml) to MultiDexApplication:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.android.multidex.myapplication">
    <application
        ...
        android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication">
        ...
    </application>
</manifest>
```

**Note:** If you are using a custom application class (see Option1 and Option2), `application` tag's `android:name` must already be set to your custom application class.

**3)** Add `multiDexEnabled true` setting to your build.gradle file:

```
defaultConfig {
    // Other settings here
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

[More information.](http://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html)

Comment: What if i am not using application class ?

Comment: @HeenaArora apply the 3rd option: "If you don't have any custom application and you don't want any, simply set your application name (at AndroidManifest.xml) to MultiDexApplication:"

Answer (score 22):

I forgot to add this line right after the super call in the onCreate() method of my custom application class :

```
 MultiDex.install(getBaseContext());
```

Thanks Kane for the solution !

Answer (score 4):

On some low-end devices adding `MultiDex.install(getBaseContext());` to MyApplication `onCreate()` did not work? causing `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`:

What did work was adding `MultiDex.install(getBaseContext());`to MyApplication `attachBaseContext(Context base)`

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
...
   @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context base) {
        super.attachBaseContext(base);
        MultiDex.install(base);
    }
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add this in Application tag of manifest file.

```
android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
```