# Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug' non-zero exit value 2

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

Error:Gradle: Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/usr/local/java/jdk1.8.0_73/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
>   
>   **This Error comes in all my projects**

**build.gradle** file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.mukesh.airpollution"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'cz.msebera.android', name: 'httpclient', version: '4.4.1.1'
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.4'
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
}

dependencies {
    compile group: 'cz.msebera.android', name: 'httpclient', version: '4.4.1.1'
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4+'
}
```

Comment: Post your build.gradle file.

Comment: This may be a multidex issue. Try to apply multidex support. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32407985/android-app-loading-library-at-runtime-on-lollipop-but-not-icecreamsandwich/36263927#36263927

Comment: @MonishKamble added gradle file

Comment: @DevrimTuncer That is not always a solution... @ Martin, Please see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36698816/gradle-what-is-a-non-zero-exit-value-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: You really should condense all the `dependencies` sections... you only need a **single** one.

Comment: Have you checked your method count?

Comment: @AndroidEnthusiast what is method count?

Comment: There is a 65K method limit which can be reached as your app grows in size due to more libararies referenced, method count tells you how many methods have been reached. Have you looked into multidex? @MartinBahr

Answer (score 1):

Try compacting your build.gradle as below (removed duplicate entry for **httpclient**) :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.mukesh.airpollution"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
compile 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.4+'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4'
compile 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.4'
compile group: 'cz.msebera.android', name: 'httpclient', version: '4.4.1.1'
}
```

Tell me whether it works?