# error when i will build a signed apk

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I get a error when i will build a signed apk. I have do a lot off things but nothing helps... I will post the messages with the error. Maybe its my fault?

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleRelease]
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkReleaseManifest
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAnimatedVectorDrawable2340Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72340Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportDesign2340Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportMediarouterV72300Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportRecyclerviewV72340Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42340Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportVectorDrawable2340Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServices902Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAds902Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAdsLite902Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAnalytics902Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAnalyticsImpl902Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppindexing902Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAppinvite902Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAuth902Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesAuthBase902Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBase902Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesBasement902Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesCast902Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesDrive902Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesFitness902Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGames902Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesGcm902Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesIdentity902Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesIid902Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesLocation902Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesMaps902Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesNearby902Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesPanorama902Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesPlus902Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesSafetynet902Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesTagmanager902Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesTagmanagerApi902Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesTasks902Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesVision902Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesWallet902Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleAndroidGmsPlayServicesWearable902Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseAnalytics902Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseAnalyticsImpl902Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseAuth902Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseAuthCommon902Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseAuthModule902Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseCommon902Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseConfig902Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseCrash902Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseDatabase902Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseDatabaseConnection902Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseIid902Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseMessaging902Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseStorage902Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComGoogleFirebaseFirebaseStorageCommon902Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareReleaseDependencies
:app:compileReleaseAidl
:app:compileReleaseRenderscript
:app:generateReleaseBuildConfig
:app:mergeReleaseShaders
:app:compileReleaseShaders
:app:generateReleaseAssets
:app:mergeReleaseAssets
:app:generateReleaseResValues
:app:generateReleaseResources
:app:mergeReleaseResources
:app:processReleaseManifest
:app:processReleaseResources
:app:generateReleaseSources
:app:incrementalReleaseJavaCompilationSafeguard
:app:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac
:app:compileReleaseJavaWithJavac - is not incremental (e.g. outputs have changed, no previous execution, etc.).
:app:compileReleaseNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileReleaseSources
:app:lintVitalRelease
:app:prePackageMarkerForRelease
:app:transformClassesWithDexForRelease
To run dex in process, the Gradle daemon needs a larger heap.
It currently has approximately 910 MB.
For faster builds, increase the maximum heap size for the Gradle daemon to more than 2048 MB.
To do this set org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048M in the project gradle.properties.
For more information see https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html
Error:The number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed 64K.
Learn how to resolve this issue at https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html
:app:transformClassesWithDexForRelease FAILED
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForRelease'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 2 mins 41.454 secs
Information:2 errors
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console
```

these are the errors

error 1:

```
Error:The number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed 64K.
Learn how to resolve this issue at https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html
```

error 2:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForRelease'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_79.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
```

I hope anyone can help me with this terrible error

Comment: Error:The number of method references in a .dex file cannot exceed 64K.
Learn how to resolve this issue at https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html

Comment: That ^ as well as `To do this set org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2048M in the project gradle.properties`

Comment: Alternatively, fix your Google Play Services dependency to not include **all** of them. Refer to the second blue box on this page. https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#add_google_play_services_to_your_project

Comment: multidex http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32407985/android-app-loading-library-at-runtime-on-lollipop-but-not-icecreamsandwich/36263927#36263927

Comment: Fix the Google play services before multidex, though

Answer (score 1):

The error 1 clearly says what the reason is. Here is the solution

Review your app's direct and transitive dependencies - Ensure any large library dependency you include in your app is used in a manner that outweighs the amount of code being added to the application. A common anti-pattern is to include a very large library because a few utility methods were useful. Reducing your app code dependencies can often help you avoid the dex reference limit.

Remove unused code with ProGuard - Configure the ProGuard settings for your app to run ProGuard and ensure you have shrinking enabled for release builds. Enabling shrinking ensures you are not shipping unused code with your APKs.

Also in your build.gradle add this

```
defaultConfig {
// Other settings here
multiDexEnabled true
}
```

Comment: Only `multiDexEnabled true` does not enable Multidex, though

Comment: it helps! Thank you!!