# Generate Signed Apk - Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithDexForRelease'

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, apk, android-proguard

I am able to run my app when i change to debug mode but it fails when i switch to release mode.

**Error:**

> Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForRelease'.
>   java.io.IOException: Please correct the above warnings first.

-

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.3"
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.application.app"
    minSdkVersion 14
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"

    multiDexEnabled true
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'),'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

dexOptions {
    incremental true
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
}

dependencies {
compile 'com.sromku:simple-storage:1.2.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:9.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.2'
compile project(':yandexmapkitlibrary')
compile 'com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0'
compile 'com.daimajia.easing:library:1.0.1@aar'
compile 'com.daimajia.androidanimations:library:1.1.3@aar'
compile 'com.github.navasmdc:MaterialDesign:1.5@aar'
compile 'com.github.dmytrodanylyk.circular-progress-button:library:1.1.3'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpclient-android', version: '4.3.5.1'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.6.2'

compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
}
```

**EDIT:**
As you can see the multidex is enabled in my build.gradle file.

**EDIT 2:**

**App.java**

```
public class App extends MultiDexApplication {

public static GoogleAnalytics analytics;
public static Tracker tracker;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    MultiDex.install(this);

    analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this);
    analytics.setLocalDispatchPeriod(1800);
    tracker = analytics.newTracker("myAnalyticsId");
    tracker.enableExceptionReporting(true);
    tracker.enableAdvertisingIdCollection(true);
}

}
```

**Manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.application.app" android:installLocation="preferExternal">

<!--permissions-->

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:logo="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

<!--...-->

</application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android : app loading library at runtime on Lollipop but not IceCreamSandwich](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32407985/android-app-loading-library-at-runtime-on-lollipop-but-not-icecreamsandwich)

Comment: @DevrimTuncer As you can see the multidex is enabled in my build.gradle file.

Comment: What about your manifest and application class? Please check the answer at the link I've shared.

Comment: remove this line, it is already included in play-services.->
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:9.0.2'

Comment: If it is saying **Please correct the above warnings first.** What are that warnings ??

Comment: Since, you have set minifyEnabled to true for release build, you need to configure Proguard for the project. Please see the Proguard related documentation for various libraries you have used.

Answer (score 2):

the problem is in using `com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.2`
instead of using all google play services try to to use just what you need

and yes you are using

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:9.0.2'
```

and then

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.2'
```

the `play-services-analytics:9.0.2` is included in `play-services:9.0.2`

just remove

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.2
```